# Re-cd into current directory

Tags: symlink, cd-command

I am in a directory which is a symlink

```bash
me@hostname:/home/me$ ls -al
the_link -> actual_a
actual_a
actual_b
actual_c
me@hostname:/home/me$ cd the_link
me@hostname:/home/me/the_link$
```

Now while I've had my shell open, some other process changed the symlink from `the_link -> actual_a` to `the_link -> actual_b` and possibly even did `rm -rf actual_a`. If I run a command in my shell it'll do weird things. Is there a way to tell `cd` to "re-cd" into the directory I'm in?

Obviously I can do

```
me@hostname:/home/me/the_link$ cd ..
me@hostname:/home/me$ cd the_link
```

but can I do it in one command?

Comment: What do you want to happen if `actual_a` was removed and then you try to cd to the directory you're in (`actual_a`) again?  Succeed?  Fail?

Comment: @SottoVoce it should retry `cd`ing into `the_link`, not `actual_a`

Comment: But if you had done a `cd actual_a`?

Comment: Then I would've asked a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd .
```

might work for you. If not, then there's of course

```
cd ../folder
```

which will go up one folder and into the named folder.

Answer (score 1):

Some shells have a built-in version of `pwd` that keeps track of your current directory by following executions of `cd`. On the other hand, the `/bin/pwd` command determines your true position in the filesystem by traversing the filesystem from your current point to the root node, generating the directory path as it goes.

You can use this to get the directory path of your current location, and then you can force a change of directory to match that new reality

```
cd "$(/bin/pwd)"
```

Example

```
mkdir /tmp/x
cd /tmp/x


    # In another terminal
    mkdir /tmp/y
    mv /tmp/x /tmp/y/z


pwd                 # "/tmp/x"   - where the shell thinks you are
/bin/pwd            # "/tmp/y/z" - where you actually are

cd "$(/bin/pwd)"
pwd                 # "/tmp/y/z"
```

Obviously this cannot not work if some process has deleted the directory in which you reside, because there is no longer a path up through `..` to the root.

Comment: POSIX `pwd`, builtin or not is required to print the contents of `$PWD` as long as it contains a path to the current working  directory. You may have tested with GNU `pwd` which is only compliant in that regard when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment.

Comment: Your solution intends to do the equivalent of `cd -P .`, but it's rather the opposite of what the OP is asking AFAICT

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas re `pwd` and `$PWD` - indeed, and for most people on a Linux-based system for most of the time, `pwd` doesn't always match the POSIX `/bin/pwd`. Re `cd -P` yes it does appear that I may have reinvented this. There are now some newer comments from the OP that offer some sort of attempt at a clarification, but at the time I wrote the answer it seemed like I was answering what was asked

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take would be to `cd` to the full path to the symbolic link.  That way, you'll always go to the real directory that the link points to.

Be sure to catch the error if the link points to a directory that doesn't exist.  Something like:

```
base_path=/home/me
link_name=the_link
link_path="${base_path}/${link_name}"

cd ${link_path} || {
  echo "$0: Could not change directory to ${link_path}: Exiting"
  exit 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
cd -- "$PWD"
```

(short for `cd -L -- "$PWD"`).

`$PWD` in POSIX shells tracks the current working directory as updated by `cd`. It keeps the symlinks in there. So you'll end up in the new directory that `the_link` points to.

On the other hand:

```
cd -P .
```

Will stay in the current working directory but update `$PWD` so it contains a canonical absolute path, free of any symlink component. If the current directory has been removed though, that won't help and the behaviour will vary with the shell.